# problems with fread() always returning 1

Tags: c, file, embedded, windows-ce, fread

I have looked at similar questions, but mine is a bit different. I make sure to open file in binary mode and to check if error occurs while reading.

File contents:

```
message1, message2, 53467
```

program to read simple file:

```
int bytesRead;
FILE* CSV;
CSV = fopen("\\Temp\\csv.txt", "rb");
char dataBuf[128];

while ( (bytesRead = fread(dataBuf, 1, sizeof(dataBuf), CSV) > 0) )
{
        if (ferror(CSV))
            //handle error

        //do stuff with dataBuf contents
}
```

fread() is always returning 1. ferror is also not entered, so no file reading error. However, the char array dataBuf is filled with the entire message from the file. I am using fread in conjunction with another function so I need to know how many bytes were read using fread(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Precedence matters.

Add parenthesis around assignment.

```
while  (  (  bytesRead = fread(dataBuf, 1, sizeof(dataBuf), CSV)  )  > 0  )   
          ^                                                       ^
```

see [C_Operator_Precedence_Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

If you see `1.5.1 File Copying` section of `The C programming Language  By Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie` You will get clear explanation on This.

Comment: .. or just move the closing bracket from behind '0' directly behind `fread(...)`. The double brackets make no sense at all

Comment: Nothing like learning the ins & outs of a function and reading detailed paragraph breakdowns of how it internally works, and it's a simple overlooked precedence issued... Thanks Gangadhar